# Is there any option to script the export for an Azure Dashboard?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

In Azure, you can create dashboards and export them using a button on the portal. However, there seems to be no option to export the ARM through an API/SDK/CLI. Am I wrong, or is this indeed a gap in the Dashboard experience?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also export the template of the resource group via [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/manage-resource-groups-cli#export-resource-groups-to-templates), [PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/manage-resource-groups-powershell#export-resource-groups-to-templates), and the [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resourcegroups/exporttemplate).

**Update:**

You can see the description [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-dashboards-create-programmatically#overview) like below:

> Shared dashboards in Azure are resources just like virtual machines
>   and storage accounts. Therefore, they can be managed programmatically
>   via the Azure Resource Manager REST APIs, the Azure CLI, Azure
>   PowerShell commands, and many Azure portal features build on top of
>   these APIs to make resource management easier.

Actually, what you download in the Azure Dashboard with the button is not a resource, so you cannot export it with commands or API. What you need is to make the dashboard template as a resource, then you can use the commands(Azure CLI or PowerShell) and API to export it.

Here is the example in the portal as a resource:

[image]

Then use the Azure CLI command to export the template like this:

```
az group deployment export -g grouName -n templateName > dashboard.json
```

Comment: This doesn't export the dashboard however, only some default properties.

Comment: @TomKuijsten What do you mean that export the dashboard?

Comment: I need the ARM template for the dashboard. I can manually create the ARM, but want to create the dashboard with the visual designed in the Azure Portal and export it in ARM format. There is a button on the portal to do this, but it seems impossible to do this through an API.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick! Stupid thing is that I need to create it as a Resource first to start editing it manually... but, it's at least a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

So I found a way doing it, downloading the JSON and upload it again after convert it into an ARM template.

It is very hacky though.

```
$resourceGroup = "your-resourcegroup"
$dashboardName = (Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ResourceType "Microsoft.Portal/dashboards").Name
$dashboardObject = Get-AzResource -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroup -ResourceType "Microsoft.Portal/dashboards" -Name $dashboardName -ExpandProperties

                $lensesHashTable = @{}
                foreach ($i in 0..($dashboardObject.Properties.lenses.Count - 1)) {
                    $lens = $dashboardObject.Properties.lenses[$i]
                    $partsHashTable = @{}
                    foreach ($j in 0..($lens.parts.Count - 1)) {
                        $partsHashTable["$j"] = $lens.parts[$j]
                    }
                    $lens | Add-Member -NotePropertyName "parts" -NotePropertyValue $partsHashTable -Force
                    $lensesHashTable["$i"] = $lens
                }

                $dashboardFormattedObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
                    properties = @{
                        lenses = $lensesHashTable
                    }
                    name = $dashboardObject.Name
                    type = 'Microsoft.Portal/dashboards'
                    location = "INSERT LOCATION"
                    tags = $dashboardObject.Tags
                    apiVersion = '2015-08-01-preview'
                }
    $dashboardFormattedObject | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100  | Out-File -FilePath dashboard.json -Encoding UTF8
```

This will give you about the same format as you would get from hitting the export button on the portal.

If you want to deploy it using an arm deployment, you will need to add the ARM structure as well.

```
$Dashboard = Get-Content -Path dashboard.json -Raw
$ARMStart = '
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
'
$ARMStart = '
]
}
'

$ARMDashboard = $ARMStart + $Dashboard + $ARMEnd
```

Export $ARMDashboard to a file, and you can deploy it again.
If you find a better solution please share ;-)